# Read Time Out al utilizar FTPCliente en Java. Justo al terminar la transferencia

Tags: java, ftp, windows-server-2012, ftpclient

espero puedan ayudarme.

Estoy tratando de guardar un archivo en un servidor FTP que tengo en WIndows Server 2012 con el siguiente código, de hecho me funcionaba sin problemas cuando tenía el servidor FTP en Linux.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(argsFtp[ftpHost]), 21);
ftpClient.login(argsFtp[ftpUsuario], argsFtp[ftpClave]);

//Verificar conexión con el servidor.
String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
    for (String aReply : replies) {
        System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
    }
}

int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    System.out.println("Imposible conectarse al servidor FTP");
}

//Verificar si se cambia de direcotirio de trabajo
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(argsFtp[rutaBackupFtp]);//Cambiar directorio de trabajo
//System.out.println("Se cambió satisfactoriamente el directorio: " + ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());

//Activar que se envie cualquier tipo de archivo
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
//ftpClient.setKeepAlive(true); 
//ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(180); // set timeout to 3 minutes
//ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(3000); 
// data transfer timeout
//ftpClient.setDataTimeout(30000);
//ftpClient.setSoTimeout(30000);
//ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
ftpClient.setCopyStreamListener(createListener());
FileInputStream buffIn = new FileInputStream(argsFtp[rutaBackupLocal]);//Ruta del archivo para enviar
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.storeFile(argsFtp[nombreBackUp], buffIn);//Ruta completa de alojamiento en el FTP

buffIn.close(); //Cerrar envio de archivos al FTP
ftpClient.logout(); //Cerrar sesión
ftpClient.disconnect();//Desconectarse del servidor
System.out.println("Enviado Backup al servidor por FTP...OK");
```

Durante el proceso reviso en el servidor y el archivo se está cargando, cuando ya termina, me muestra el siguiente error y se borra el archivo.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182) at
>   org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
>   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:321) at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300) at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:732) at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.completePendingCommand(FTPClient.java:1853)
>   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:694)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:639)
>   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:2030)
>   at eidybackup.EidyBackup.enviarBackupFTP(EidyBackup.java:338) at
>   eidybackup.EidyBackup.main(EidyBackup.java:172)

Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo resolviste?

Comment: Aun no. Ya he probado ampliando el DataTimeout, el soTimeout, e incluso el reduciendo el controlKeepAliveTimeout. Persiste el problema

Comment: Pues no es reducirlo si no ampliar el tiempo que espera